# Build of facebook ios sdk 3.8 aborts because of 64 bit target

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, 64-bit, ios7

If I build the facebook sdk 3.8 with the default configuration, the build process aborts with the following error message:

```
error: invalid deployment target '6.0.0' for architecture 'arm64'
(requires '7.0.0' or later)
1 error generated.

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
ProcessPCH
/var/folders/fm/jtl_yzt55wq_rtvdt0d1yzfc0000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTool
s/5.0-5A1413/Xcode/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/facebook_ios_sdk_Prefix-dfvw
jzbcrxnuwddxjkudqnqllrma/facebook_ios_sdk_Prefix.pch.pch
facebook_ios_sdk_Prefix.pch normal arm64 objective-c
com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)

FATAL: XCode build failed for platform: iphoneos.
```

I could change the deployment target of Release64 and Debug64 to iOS 7.0 and the build process works probably. But I'm wondering, that it seems that no one else has this problem. Any idea, if there could by another solution without altering the facebook code?

Answer (score 0):

The complier when running build_framework.sh is looking at the `src/facebook-ios-sdk.xcodeproj`. Open that project and set the development target to 7.0, then build the framework again.

Comment: Yes, thats what i did. And its i working with this setting. But I'am still wondering, that is seems no one other have this problem and also that Facebook did not change it yet...